# How to use mail lists with bbdb and message mode?

Tags: message-mode, bbdb

I'm trying to follow along here to get bbdb to insert lists of email addresses into my "to" fields when I hit something like "TAB". http://bbdb.sourceforge.net/bbdb.html#SEC39

The section on lists refers to a mail-abbrevs package, which I can't seem to find anywhere. Is there a simple way to just insert a list into my email? The instructions I'm finding seem to be dated.

Comment: I Googled:  **"mail-abbrevs"** and found this at the top of the list of search results:  http://web.mit.edu/deberg/emacs/elisp/mail-abbrevs.el and here is a newer version:  https://github.com/sbp/lemacs/blob/master/lisp/modes/mail-abbrevs.el  I would recommending Googling instead **"mail-abbrevs.el"** and look carefully at the revision dates to find the most recent available on the net.  Once you have done some detective work to find the most recent version available, please consider sharing that link with us and update your question if you still need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org#auto-complete-mail-address

I use counsel-bbdb but company-bbdb is also enabled.

To insert multiple mail address:
Just press `C-M-n` in the candidates window. It's built in feature of `ivy-mode` which `counsel-bbdb` is dependent on.

See http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-multiple-selections-and-actions-keep-minibuffer-open for more key bindings.

To insert multiple mail addresses by `mail alias`, please `M-x counsel-bbdb-expand-mail-alias`.

Comment: I tried counsel-bbdb but it looks like it is only good for inserting addresses one at  a time, not as a list.

Comment: Multi-selection feature is already there. check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using mail aliases of bbdb for lists of mail addresses (as chen bin already mentioned).